# How to delete python on new M1 from back up

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I have a new m1 laptop and I transferred all my data from my old machine onto. Including old python installations. I can't work out how to find and delete all of them so I can clean install with brew in the new version.
Brew on M1 also looks in a different directory for installs now so it can't find the old versions (inside local/bin) to uninstall them.

Comment: Maybe start with something like `find -type f -name '*python*'` and figure out which are the python-related files that are safe to delete.

Comment: If the files are not copied to a directory which is on your `PATH` (or Python's `sys.path` etc etc) they are harmless as such. It's not clear which problem you are attempting to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If `brew list python`fails, try “the brute force” method, i.e. search your entire drive for executables that are called `python-×.×`.

**This command will not delete anything. It is up to you to manually delete the files you don’t want anymore.**

```sh
find / -perm +111 -type f -or -type l 2> /dev/null | grep '/python[-0123456789\.]*$'
```

**Explanation**

```sh
find / \                  # search starting at the topmost level of your drive 
    -perm +111 \          # executables files only
    -type f -or -type l \ # only files or symlinks
    2> /dev/null \        # discard errors 
    | grep '/python[-0123456789\.]*$' # regexp to filter names
```